# Javascript - If statement working, but the else doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, colors, onclick

I have  a script that runs when a specific element is clicked on. The script changes the background color of a div. When the user clicks on the div the background color must change to #4aa3c3, but when the user clicks on the div again, it must change back to a #fafafa. The if statement works, but for some reason, once the color is changed to #4aa3c3, it won't change back to normal. It seems like my else statement isn't working. Am I doing something wrong?

```
    function Active() {

    if (document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor !== "#4aa3c3"){
        document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#4aa3c3";
        } else {
        document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#fafafa";
        }
}
```

Comment: Browsers report color values in ways that may not correspond to the color code you used originally. Add a `console.log()` call to see what the color value actually is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you try some basic debugging, like

```
console.log(document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor);
```

Do you see the problem? Chances are, you're getting something like:

```
"rgb(74, 163, 195)"
```

So that's why the `if` isn't working as you'd like. But that's not your biggest issue.

The real problem is that you are using Presentation (CSS) to define Behaviour (JS). On top of that, you're using Behaviour to define Presentation.

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('test').classList.toggle('toggled');
```

And use CSS to define a style like:

```
#test {background-color: #fafafa}
#test.toggled {background-color: #4aa3c3}
```

Comment: Spoken like an MVC master

Comment: Thank you - I should've mentioned that I'm a total beginner to Javascript, but I think you gathered as much.

Answer (score 0):

Would agree with the answer above - however to add another dimension - if you ever did need to change the returned RBG values to hex you could try something like this which would allow the code to work as stated in the original question.

```
<script>


function hex(x) {
    return ("0"+x.toString(16)).slice(-2);
}

function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}

function CheckIfColorIsCorrect()
{

        var hex = rgb2hex(document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor);

        if (hex != "#4aa3c3"){
        document.getElementById("topbar").style.backgroundColor = "#4aa3c3";
        } else {
        document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#fafafa";
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ew... `function hex(x) {return ("0"+x.toString(16)).slice(-2);}` is much nicer than having an array of hexits :D